# Print from nested array using map, reduce and filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

The final purpose is to get one for each name in the following array.
(Alike the commented out rows at bottom of below snippet)

If there is the same name, only the one with the largest count, and if there is a duplicate count, only the one with a higher version.

I tried to use the combination of map, reduce.
Please help me to solve this out.

```
//Original array
var arr = [
  {'name': 'b', 'version': '103', 'count': 10}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '0.1b', 'count': 73}, 
  {'name': 'b', 'version': '109', 'count': 67}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '1.0.3', 'count': 100}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '2.1.0', 'count': 100}, 
  {'name': 'c', 'version': 'a103', 'count': 30}, 
  {'name': 'c', 'version': 'a111', 'count': 100}
];

//expected console output
// { name: 'a', version: '2.1.0', count: 100 }
// { name: 'b', version: '109', count: 67 }
// { name: 'c', version: 'a111', count: 100 }
```

First, as a 'part' of that process, I've tried to get 'a's from the array.

```
var filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item.name === 'a');

var m = Math.max(...(filteredArr.map(({count}) => count))),
  maxes = arr.map(({count}) => count).reduce((p,c,i,a) => c ==  m ? p.concat(i) : p,[]);
console.log(maxes);
```

I expected to get [3, 4] from above, but it prints [3, 4, 6].

=====

Additional question:

How can I handle this another original to expected one.

```
//Another original array.
var arr2 = [ 
  { name: 'a', version: '0.1', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '209', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '213', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '213', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '209', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 1 }
];

//expected output
// { name: 'a', version: '0.1', count: 1 },
// { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 5 },
// { name: 'b', version: '209', count: 2 },
// { name: 'b', version: '213', count: 2 }
```

Comment: Show the code you tried and how it failed

Comment: What is your definition of higher version when the version value is unpredictable?

Comment: runnable snippet and console.log can help

Comment: Your expected output [3,4] in no way represents the rules you stated above. Please explain how that output/code is even related to the rules you laid out.

Comment: @KienHTJust compare the versions as a ascii is enough!

Comment: @RandyCasburn That was a pre-process to compare versions after getting [3, 4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the object for each name.

```js
var arr = [
  {'name': 'b', 'version': '103', 'count': 10}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '0.1b', 'count': 73}, 
  {'name': 'b', 'version': '109', 'count': 67}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '1.0.3', 'count': 100}, 
  {'name': 'a', 'version': '2.1.0', 'count': 100}, 
  {'name': 'c', 'version': 'a103', 'count': 30}, 
  {'name': 'c', 'version': 'a111', 'count': 100}
];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{name, version, count})=>{
  if(!acc[name] || acc[name] && 
          (acc[name].count < count 
           || acc[name].count === count && acc[name].version < version)){
    acc[name] = {name, version, count};
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do in the second case is aggregating the `count` property for entries with both the same `name` and `version` (similar to the `COUNT` + `GROUP BY` queries in `SQL` databases).

In that case, you could first compute a `dictionary_res` indexed by `name` at the first level, and by `version` at the second level:

```js
dictionary_res = arr2.reduce((acc, { name, version, count }) => {
  if (!acc[name] || (acc[name] && !acc[name][version])) {
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {}
    acc[name][version] = { count: count }
  } else {
    acc[name][version]['count'] = acc[name][version]['count'] + count
  }
  return acc
}, {})
```

`dictionary_res` yields a value pretty close to the one you want:

```js
{
  a: { '0.1': { count: 1 } },
  b:
  { '209': { count: 2 }, '213': { count: 2 }, '216': { count: 5 } }
}
```

However, you still need to turn that into an array to fully achieve what you want:

```js
array_res = Object.keys(dictionary_res).reduce((acc, name) => {
  Object.keys(dictionary_res[name]).forEach((version) => (
    acc.push({ name, version, count: dictionary_res[name][version]['count'] })
  ))
  return acc
}, [])
```

`array_res` now yields the expected value:

```js
[ { name: 'a', version: '0.1', count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', version: '209', count: 2 },
  { name: 'b', version: '213', count: 2 },
  { name: 'b', version: '216', count: 5 } ]
```

Comment: Superb! Actually, I need to input the result of the second case (your answer) into the first one. Thank you.